# How to set the width and height of the current window in electron

Tags: electron

I have set the window width and height at the time of it's creation and now again I want to change the width and height of the same window when I calls the ipc main process.
Here is my code

```
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 448, // here I have set the width and height
    height: 650,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    minimizable: true,
    maximizable: true,
    closable: true,
  })

  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, './view/loginWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

.....
....
```

Now I am calling the ipc method

```
ipcMain.on('userRegLinkClicked', (event, data) => {
  win.setSize({
    width: 448,
    height: 850
  })
}
```

But nothing works instead I get the error `TypeError: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from #<Object>`

Answer (score 1):

[window.setSize](https://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#winsetsizewidth-height-animate) does not take an options object with width/height, but instead uses width/height and additional parameters as direct arguments.

Use this instead:

```
ipcMain.on('userRegLinkClicked', (event, data) => {
  win.setSize(448, 850);
}
```